# using Stanford coreNLP openIE throws outofmemory exception after I replaced the language model

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use coreNLP opneIE for other human language like Chinese(no problem with default English model and the Chinese model is the latest one got from StanfordNLP page).My code here (example from Stanford NLP doc page)

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] argv){
    try{
        // Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //load properties file
        InputStream in =new FileInputStream(new File("/properties/chinese.properties"));
        //load file stream to properties
        props.load(in);
        in.close();
        //initialize pipeline(problem occurred here)
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        System.out.println("Load successfully!");

        // Annotate an example document.
        //Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
        Annotation doc = new Annotation("克林顿说，华盛顿将逐步落实对韩国的经济援助。");
        pipeline.annotate(doc);

        for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
            Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
            // Print the triples
            for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
                System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
                        triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
                        triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
                        triple.objectLemmaGloss());
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I was initializing pipeline, the exception out of memory threw to me as following :

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator openie
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.ClauseSplitter - Loading clause splitter from edu/stanford/nlp/models/naturalli/clauseSearcherModel.ser.gz ... done [0.0073 seconds]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1875)
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.NaturalLogicWeights.<init>(NaturalLogicWeights.java:59)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.<init>(OpenIE.java:210)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.openie(AnnotatorImplementations.java:260)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$59(StanfordCoreNLP.java:513)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$31/1156060786.apply(Unknown Source)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getDefaultAnnotatorPool$65(StanfordCoreNLP.java:533)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$37/2101842856.get(Unknown Source)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:118)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:146)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:447)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:146)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:133)
```

By other questions' answers ,I tried to change JVM's runtime memory(2GB-4GB) but no effects.So how can I solve this problem because it confused me that why it occurred when I changed the language model but no problem with default English one.Thx guys.

Comment: Looks like your JVM does not have enough memory. I know you already increased the heap size, but did you try to set `-Xms<size>` and `-Xmx<size>`? And don't forget to specify the unit of the size.

Comment: +1 to Tobias' response. But, I'm curious: does OpenIE even remotely work for Chinese? It's certainly not meant to -- any success you get with it is entirely unintended.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann : Of course i did , set -Xms<size> with 2GB and -Xmx<size> with 4GB in Intellij's 'idea.vmoptions' file 
`-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops'`But no effects, the issue still occurred(Exception above is copied from the case after changing memory size same before changed).@GaborAngeli : I think openIE can work for Chinese because Stanford online demo can be changed to Chinese mode and extract Chinese relation.

Comment: I think you may have sent Intellij's vm options for running itself, rather than what it uses to run programs. Try adding -mx4g to the VM options field in your run configuration (see the drop-down at the top right).

Comment: @Gabor Angeli : Thx Angeli, it works perfectly, but result disappointed me :(.It can't extract complex sentence for Chinese even though sentence as above "克林顿说，华盛顿将逐步落实对韩国的经济援助。".I guess that they transfer the work to other language just change the model for annotating but not train the classifier and design the triple parse pattern .So another question , how can I use it for other language?Should I train the linear classifier by myself and design the pattern?

Comment: Yeah, I'd have been surprised if it works. Likely, both the clause splitter and the relation triple segmenter would have to be remade for Chinese, which is not a small feat. If you're interested, I can help guide you to the coffee, but I don't have enough time or knowledge of Chinese to do it myself.

Comment: @GaborAngeli : That's great , thx very much for your help.I am studying the Chinese openIE for web contents so try to use your state-of-art work for starting.You may just guide me how to feat it , I will remade it by myself(Sorry for wasting your time).Finally,thx for your work and help again.

Comment: The place to start would be Universal Dependencies in Chinese. Then, I'd look at the [triple segmenter](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/RelationTripleSegmenter.java) and the associated [test cases](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/test/src/edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/RelationTripleSegmenterTest.java), adapting the extraction of triples from atomic utterances. Then, the clause splitter lives [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/ClauseSplitterSearchProblem.java).

Comment: @GaborAngeli : Thx very much,I will have a try :)